# How to insulate a wall with existing radiant barrier on siding

Tags: insulation, garage, shed

Revised :

With little real information to go on. The only info I could get from the manufacturer (LP) is to leave a 3/4 air gap.  That's come a little late because I had to keep moving forward.

So - what I've actually done.

North wall. Little to no direct sunlight.  Rockwool filling between studs > 7/16 OSB. That's it.

South Wall. 50% direct sunlight. Added 1" strip of wood to front faces of studs. Filled cavity flush to front with Rockwool. Achieved a 1" air gap to radiant barrier. And will cover with 7/16 OSB.

Going vapor barrier free - in hopes that the walls can still "breath" as needed year round.

The roof I am going to bite the bullet and do foam board + spray foam between the joists.

Guess I will find out in a few years if this is a total disaster.

---

I have spent hours trying to figure this one out.  I have a new detached garage on concrete slab floor. The building was installed by tuff shed.  There is a silver radiant barrier on all the walls and the roof.

[image]

Step 1. How to insulate the walls?

The walls themselves dont get that match direct sunlight - so I am thinking of sacrificing the radiant quality and putting insulation right on the surface. Ie no air gap.  Total mistake?

The current idea:

Inside = 7/16 OSB > Insulation R15 Rockwool (between studs)> Exterior wall

Garage will be heated and cooled. Located in Colorado Zone 5.

The main questions are:

- does there need to be a vapor barrier? Or Vapor Retarder? And if so - where?
- should I put in a spacer to hold off the Rockwool from direct contact with the silver? If so - does that space need a way to vent?

If Rockwool is the wrong material - boards are an option also. But seem much more labor intensive spray foaming all the edges and offer lesser R value. And again the questions about keeping a 1-inch air gap or going flush against the backing are still in play.

---

Step 2: The Roof. Which I am saving for another day....

Thank you!

Comment: air gap would hep

Comment: This may answer your questions;  
 https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105031/rigid-foam-board-in-walls-between-studs-plus-fiberglass-batt

Comment: Create an air gap seems the conventional wisdom. I still cannot get a definitive answer on whether the radiant lining itself is already a vapor barrier. If it is - then bymy understanding one would NOT want a vapor barrier behind the interior wall - as that would be trapping insulation between to vapor barriers ... Which I hear is a bad thing?  I have no idea really. I know some things but insulation tech isn't one of them. I'd really like to know a solid plan before I start buying materials though if anyone out there has experience.