# Moisture barriers when finishing a basement?

Tags: insulation, basement, waterproofing, basement-refinishing

So I know this is kind of a rabbit hole question -- mostly because I've been down that hole for the last month reading articles that disagree with each other. I'm hoping the folks here can give me a more practical answer..

I live in Maryland, so it does dip below zero on occasion here. My basement is all concrete, and I've never seen a drop of water. Realizing that concrete sweats (even if I can't see it), my plan is;

- put up 3/4" EPS
- fill the walls with standard insulation
- cover with a plastic moisture barrier sheet before putting up drywall
- Dricore subfloor

My question is basically; is that the right way to go? Do I need to change anything to make sure I stay moisture/mold-free?

Comment: When you say "standard insulation". Do you mean unfaced fiberglass insulation? You're basically wedging fiberglass insulation in between two vapor retarders/barriers with the EPS and then a plastic vapor barrier--most insulation manufacturer installation instructions that I have read recommend against multiple vapor barriers.

Comment: Also, what methods/materials are you using to frame the walls? Regular wood = mold food.

Comment: @statueuphemism Yes, EPS, then fiberglass (or perhaps blown). Code in MD says pressure treated 2x4 for the bottom plate, and regular 2x4 for the rest, so that was my plan..

Comment: Have you considered using metal studs? They will not harbor mold, are lighter to work with, and they won't warp or check like wood which means you're guaranteed a straight/smooth surface for hanging drywall.

Comment: @statueuphemism I have actually, but I keep reading you gotta fill the channel with wood or mounting things to the wall winds up having problems?

Comment: For a retrofit, in your climate, *no vapor barrier!!!*. The EPS acts as a vapor *retarder* which is what you want. Please read my detailed answer here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8644/1209

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would **NEVER** put up plastic on the outside basement wall. All you will do is trap the moisture in the wall and create an environment perfect for mold. Especially with batt or blown insulation behind it.

EPS actually breathes water vapor and is better than standard insulation for vapor passage.

Moisture from the wall has nowhere to go but through the wall and needs to dry to the inside. The ground outside is already full of moisture so it can't dry to the outside.

Check out this [website dedicated to building science](https://buildingscience.com/document-search).

Read the various articles on vapor barriers and mold. These articles are written by experienced individuals, some with PhDs in building construction like [this guy](https://buildingscience.com/users/joseph-lstiburek).

These people know a lot more about construction than any site I have ever seen.

Good Luck!

Comment: If I could vote up multiple times I would. Your links to the Building science site is the same outfit that the company I used to work for 22 years teamed up with this guy to develop renovation techniques for weather and basement damp proofing. Met and did a seminar with Dr. Joe.

Comment: I've actually been reading this site a lot :) I just can't translate the PHd stuff to my application. Are you saying just EPS, fiberglass in the walls, and then drywall? And let the moisture dry thru the drywall into the basement?

Comment: I think on that site they recommend EPS and batter boards with moisture resistant drywall (greenboard). No fiberglass, plastic sheeting, or cellulose.

Comment: @XeroxDucati just EPS. Don't use fiberglass (no real point). I also recommend using paperless wallboard (densarmor).

Comment: @ArchonOSX what's a batter board? Are you talking about just putting 1" furring strips right into the eps/concrete without bothering with framing? If so, how would things like power outlet boxes get mounted? and how would wiring get run?

Comment: @XeroxDucati they make fiberglass-faced sheetrock (Densarmour is one brand name). No paper = no place for mildew/mold to grow. The drawback, though is IT IS ITCHY TO INSTALL! :)

Comment: @DA01 I'm hiring a crew to drywall, so they can itch :D I like the paperless sheetrock idea. I guess my only remaining question is do I still frame these walls or do I just attach 2x4s straight to the masonry?

Comment: Yeah a batter board is basically "1 by" material laid flat. Like 1x3's or 1x4's. You could use pressure treated lumber for this. Then they make extremely shallow 15/16" electrical boxes for these walls. It requires that each box gets a separate electrical drop from a junciton box. There is basically no room for joints in the box. They also make special receptacles that are flatter.

Comment: @XeroxDucati you want to frame a wall on the *inside* of the insulation. See my explanation here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8644/1209

Comment: @ArchonOSX I think you mean "batten" board? Batter boards are used for foundation layouts. When used on a foundation wall, though, they're usually called "furring strips". That said, you don't want to do that in this case, as you want a continuous sheet of insulation between the wall and the foundation.

Comment: @DA01 I actually read your explanation article :) So I'm curious on the metal studs -- they're very appealing, but you mentioned you filled them with wood for places to mount cabinets (or in my case a big tv).. doesn't that just provide a different set of wood to grow mold?

Comment: @XeroxDucati yes though...if you still have that much moisture, you may have other bigger issues. Once you have the basement fully wrapped in insulation, and perhaps keep a dehumidifier running, it should be fine.

Comment: That said...you *can* buy high-gauge metal studs that *can* support wall mounted cabinets and TVs. You may have to go to a commercial contractor to find them, though (I've purchased them from big sheetrock companies that do the interiors of large office buildings)

Comment: @DA01 Yes I stand corrected "batten" board.