# Basement insulation in front of vapor barrier

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

I am getting ready to finish my basement. We have lived in the house for 7 years, never any moisture or water issues in the basement. It currently has pink insulation from ceiling to 12" above floor with a plastic vapor barrier sheet all the way around. The back portion of the basement is a walkout so the wall is completely exposed on the outside.

When I frame out the walls should I put something like an R14 insulation in the framed out walls in front of the vapour barrier?

Would that create any moisture problems having insulation on both sides of the vapor barrier?

Comment: Old question, granted, but why would you insulate walls that are already insulated? Relatively little heat escapes through below-grade basement walls, so R-11 (or better) is usually considered suitable.

Answer (score -1):

Never use plastic for a vapor barrier. It just breeds mold.

Moisture migrates through the wall and is trapped on the surface of the plastic with nowhere to go. Especially on the walls that are covered by the ground.

Refer to this Q & A [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/124210/moisture-barriers-when-finishing-a-basement/124212#124212) before you proceed.

Check this website [here](https://buildingscience.com/document-search) for some excellent articles on this subject.

Good Luck!

Comment: You can't make blanket statements like your opening sentence without understanding how things are done in various climates. Here in Minnesota, every home built is fully lined with plastic and sealed with caulk. We also install house wrap on the exterior. It's what works here.